# C++ : How to populate the second column of a listview via code

Tags: listview, c++-cli

I have a listview with 2 columns. I can easily populate the first column by using:

```
commandHistory->Items->Add("Column 1 Entry Successful!");
```

But how would I go about populating the second column at the same time?

Comment: You appear to be using C++/CLI which is a Microsoft specific extension. The question should be tagged appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the SubItems property.  Like this:

```
             ListViewItem^ item = commandHistory->Items->Add("Frist!");
             item->SubItems->Add("2nd column");
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a [ListViewItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.aspx).

Here's an example:

```
ListView^ lv = gcnew ListView();
lv->Columns->Add("Language");
lv->Columns->Add("Creator");
ListViewItem^ a = gcnew ListViewItem(gcnew array<String^> { L"C++", L"Stroustrup" });
ListViewItem^ b = gcnew ListViewItem(gcnew array<String^> { L"Java", L"Gosling" });
lv->Items->AddRange(gcnew array<ListViewItem^> { a, b });
```

Comment: Do I have to give them names such as a, b etc? Because once they are in there, I don't want to have to access them again. The code I gave in the OP is enough, I just need to know (if possible) how to add to the second column (sub item) at the same time.